# Regex (disallow dots between text)

Tags: regex

How can I disallow dots between text, specifically in this regex

```
^$|^[a-zA-Z\\u0080-\\uFFFF0-9\s\-#',\.]{0,}$
```

So dot is allowed, but I only want to allow if one space follows it like Dr. Smith, but not foo.bar

Should match:

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

lorem dr. ipsum sit amet
```

Shouldn't match:

```
lorem dr.ipsum sit amet
```

Comment: Please provide some test strings and what you want to match in that test string

Comment: simply by modifying the regex you provided, `^$|^(?:[a-zA-Z\u0080-\uFFFF0-9\s\-#',]|\.(?=\s)){0,}$` this should work. But there should be a better way to implement it, but need some test strings to understand what exactly you want to match and what you don't want to match(all the cases)

Comment: Explain what you want to do (or expect from) `\\u0080-\\uFFFF0-9\s\-#',\.`.   Just with simple letters this seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/dGEv9w/1

Comment: Actually this is already really good, thanks @K450! Added some text to the description.

Comment: Only one thing, if there is a way to disallow multiple spaces between words, like this: `lorem ipsum dolor sit    amet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to meet your conditions:

```sh
^(?=.{1,30}$)[a-zA-Z\u0080-\uFFFF0-9#',-]+(?:\.? [a-zA-Z\u0080-\uFFFF0-9#',-]+)*$
```

[Check RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJZpXC/3)

This matches 1+ of allowed characters inside `[...]` *optionally* followed by an optional dot and a single space followed by same set of allowed characters.

`(?=.{1,30}$)` restricts max allowed length to 30.

Comment: Is this what is meant to happen?  `\\ matches the character \ with index 9210 (5C16 or 1348) literally (case sensitive)
u008 matches a single character in the list u08 (case sensitive)`  ?  (just curious)

Comment: I just copy pasted from OP. It should be `^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\uFFFF0-9#',-]+(?:\.? [a-zA-Z\u0080-\uFFFF0-9#',-]+)*$` (edited)

Comment: Cool, thanks @anubhava. Can I add character limit as well for the whole? Like {0,10}. I thought replacing * at the end would work, but it doesn't

Comment: I have added assertion for max length in my answer. Please check

Comment: It wors perfectly, thanks a lot @anubhava!